# Plotting Base-vectors not working properly

Tags: plotting, graphics, linear-algebra, vector

I'm stuck on a issue that I can't seem to solve. After defining values for V, W and x, I'm supposed to Plot two base-vectors in the base V and with the vector x in the same picture. I'm supposed to use this command:

```
Graphics [ { Blue , Arrow [ { { 0 , 0} , V [ [ 1 ] ] } ] ,
Blue , Arrow [ { { 0 , 0} , V [ [ 2 ] ] } ] ,
Red , Arrow [ { { 0 , 0} , x } ] } ,
Axes −> True , AxesLabel −> { ’ ’X’ ’ , ’ ’Y’ ’ } ]
```

but it doesn't work. I've tried to paste it in, and re-write it but nothing seems to work. This is my code atm:

[image]

Comment: Please provide complete Mathematica code! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
V = RandomInteger[{0, 6}, {2, 2}]
W = RandomInteger[{0, 6}, {2, 2}]
x = {6, 6}

Graphics[{Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, V[[1]]}], Blue,Dashed,Arrow[{{0, 0}, V[[2]]}], Red, Dashing[{}],Arrow[{{0, 0}, x}]}, Axes -> True,AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my god. The quotation marks is what screwed me over. I'm supposed to plot the components for x in both the system, with the use of (Dashed, Line) and its supposed to look something like this:https://gyazo.com/2063a09b18bc77c40da1856bb51d4521  . How would I do that?

Comment: Look for information Option `Dashed` or `Dashing`

Comment: I've done that, but I don't know how to apply it to my task, which is the problem im facing

Comment: My answer is edited now with blue arrow dashed. `Dashing[{}]` makes a solid line.

Comment: Ah, I understand. But I don't know what to do with the x-values in the question...

Comment: Aren't you the one who asked the question?

Comment: Obviously yes. I don't think you understand what I mean. What I'm trying to say is, I dont know how to plot the components for x in the system.

Comment: In the plot(see my answer) it seems that `v[[2]] ==x`. That's why the x-plot isn't visible.